# Formatting a print statement with numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, function, numpy

I am trying to print two numpy arrays in relation to their order. I am trying to do this function without a for loop. I do not know the approach I could take to doing this. I essentially want to turn the vanilla Python version into numpy form.

```
a = np.arange(0, 15, 1)
b = np.arange(0, 150, 10)
```

Vanilla Python version

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    print("when a is", a[i], "b is", b[i])
```

Expected output:

```
when a is 1 b is 10
when a is 2 b is 20
when a is 3 b is 30
...
```

Comment: If you are printing pairs separately there's nothing wrong with a loop.  Printing is relatively slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm written this long winded answer because I suspect you don't quite understand the value of "no loop" when working with `numpy`.

So you have 2 arrays of the same length:

```
In [256]: a = np.arange(0,15,1)
     ...: b = np.arange(0,150,10)
In [257]: a
Out[257]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
In [258]: b
Out[258]: 
array([  0,  10,  20,  30,  40,  50,  60,  70,  80,  90, 100, 110, 120,
       130, 140])
In [259]: a.shape
Out[259]: (15,)
In [260]: b.shape
Out[260]: (15,)
```

A straight forward print of each pair - this would even be faster if `a` and `b` were lists instead of arrays, but the real time limit is the print, not the iteration.  (I'm using the newish `f` formating for convenience.)

```
In [261]: for i,j in zip(a,b):print(f'when a is {i}, b is {j}')
when a is 0, b is 0
when a is 1, b is 10
when a is 2, b is 20
....
when a is 13, b is 130
when a is 14, b is 140
```

We can make a 2d array from the two arrays:

```
In [262]: np.array((a,b))
Out[262]: 
array([[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,
         13,  14],
       [  0,  10,  20,  30,  40,  50,  60,  70,  80,  90, 100, 110, 120,
        130, 140]])
```

And if you prefer a column display:

```
In [263]: np.array((a,b)).T
Out[263]: 
array([[  0,   0],
       [  1,  10],
       [  2,  20],
       [  3,  30],
       ...
       [ 13, 130],
       [ 14, 140]])
```

That makes a (15,2) array. There are several other ways of constructing such an array.

While the general layout matches your print, including all the extra text will take more work.  `numpy` isn't optimized for string work; it's a numeric tool.  If you want the fancy formatting stick with the python loop.

`np.savetxt` writes a `csv` file. It iterates on the rows, and for each does a formatted write like:

```
In [268]: for row in Out[263]: print('When a is %d, b is %d'%tuple(row))
When a is 0, b is 0
When a is 1, b is 10
When a is 2, b is 20
When a is 3, b is 30

In [270]: np.savetxt('test.txt', Out[263], fmt='when a is %d, b is %d')
In [271]: cat test.txt
when a is 0, b is 0
when a is 1, b is 10
when a is 2, b is 20
when a is 3, b is 30
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new array with `a` and `b` and then use [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html):

```py
a = np.arange(0,15,1)
b = np.arange(0,150,10)
c = np.array([a, b])
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: print(f'when a is {x[0]} b is {x[1]}'), 0, c)
```

Output:

```
when a is 0 b is 0
when a is 1 b is 10
when a is 2 b is 20
when a is 3 b is 30
when a is 4 b is 40
...
```

Btw, I don't think `print` is the correct usage of this function - it returns a series of `None`'s. If you want a series, of strings, remove the `print`.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with a for loop exactly?

If you really really don't want to use a for loop then

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(0, 15, 1)
b = np.arange(0, 150, 10)

text_1 = np.array(['what a is']*len(a))
text_2 = np.array(['b is']*len(a))

print(np.array([text_1, a, text_2, b]).transpose())
```

will work, but with lots of quotation marks everywhere. Note that it will only work if a and b are of the same length. You can use [np.set_printoptions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) to format exactly how it looks.